# kohana file validate error

Tags: php, kohana

I can't seem to figure out the cause of this error when trying to validate a image upload

```
$imagevalidate = Validate::factory($_FILES);
$imagevalidate->rules($_FILES['profile_picture'], array(
    'Upload::valid' => array(),
    'Upload::not_empty' => array(),
    'Upload::type' => array(
        'Upload::type' => array(
            'jpg',
            'png',
            'gif'
        )
    ),
    'Upload::size' => array(
        '1M'
    )
));
if ($imagevalidate->check()) {
    $picture = Upload::save($_FILES['profile_picture']);
    Image::factory($picture)->resize(200, 200, Image::WIDTH)->save();
    $profile->profile_picture = basename($picture);
} else {
    $errors = $imagevalidate()->errors('profile/edit');
}
```

I am getting this error ErrorException [ Warning ]: Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Comment: What is the version of Kohana ?

Answer (score 2):

in 3.2 example pass:

```
    $array = Validation::factory($_FILES);
    $array->rule('file', 'Upload::size', array(':value', '900KiB'));
    $array->rule('file', 'Upload::type', array(':value', array('jpg', 'png', 'gif')));
    $array->rule('file', 'Upload::image', array(':value', array(640, 480)));
    $array->rule('file', 'Upload::valid');

    if($array->check())
    {
        if(Upload::save($_FILES['file']))
            echo 'uploaded';
    }
    else
    {
        echo Debug::vars($array->errors('profile/edit'));
    }
```

messages file:

```
  return array(
'file'  =>  array(
    'Upload::type'  =>  'blabla',
    'Upload::size'  =>  'blabla',
    'Upload::image' =>  'blablan',
    'Upload::valid' =>  'blablabla'
),
```

);

un.. hope helpful:)

Comment: apparently Upload::image doesn't allow for "empty" files and, unlike the other 3 rules, it will throw a validation error if no file is passed to the form and your example would fail in such a case.